# Changing Assembly name sql without dropping it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, .net-assembly

do you know if there is a way to change the name of an assembly in transact-sql. I am using sql server. [Alter Assembly](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186711.aspx) look like you can't change the name with it. Do you know a trick or something using a script?

The script I use to create the Assembly:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [RocheWebService2Sql]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 'C:\Program Files\stxkk0\Assemblies\Wssdaw2Sql.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS

GO
```

I don't want to drop the assembly as a solution.

Comment: Given that dropping and recreating seems to be the standard expected process, could you tell us more about *why* you don't want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First drop any functions that reference it

```
DROP FUNCTION XXXX
```

Then drop the assembly

```
DROP ASSEMBLY YYYYY
```

Then create the assembly with the right name

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY WWWW from 'C:\MY.dll' -- WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
```

The recreate your functions

```
CREATE FUNCTION XXXX(Your parameters)
    RETURNS INT(your return type)
    AS EXTERNAL NAME WWWW.[Namespace].YourMethod
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the old and create with the new name